# Can mold survive on copper?

Tags: water, heater

Also, does copper kill mold and mold *spores*?
Does copper prevent mold such as 'black mold even.

Comment: Welcome to SE. As it is, your question is about biochemistry more than home improvement. Maybe revise to explain the actual problem and ask something about that instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about biochemistry and not home improvement

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimicrobial_properties_of_copper#Fungi I agree with closing this question here though. Try on http://biology.stackexchange.com or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

To;dr - Yes, and probably.

Copper has been used for a couple thousand years now for piping and as a part of brass for plumbing fittings and handrails. It is naturally anti-fungal and anti-bacterial. You don't need antibiotics or cleaners on real brass handrails.

The Romans used it for plumbing and although they really didn't know anything about bacteria it kept them healthier. (Unfortunately, they also used lead which is poisonous and may have contributed to insanity in their upper clas population.)

Copper is also used in asphalt shingles and as a paint additive, as an inexpensive anti-fungal and anti-mold agent to prevent moss, mold, and mildew growth.

Comment: Lead is still used in plumbing.  See the travesty in [Flint Michigan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flint_water_crisis).  It's scale that protects us from it and likely protected the Romans too (depending on the water source and it's mineral content.)

Comment: Yes unfortunately legacy plumbing that contains lead will be with us for years. In most places, all the potable water fittings and soldered copper installed today are required by to be lead free now for new systems. Some of those silly regulations that save people's lives every day.